# need support utilizing FM_1808(F-RAM Memory) for the data extraction using structure pointers

Tags: c, embedded

I am working on field oriented control for PMSM. I'm using customized hardware, and unfortunetly i can't see the speed responses and current signal straight on the oscilliscope through pins. So i need to save data in FM_1808(F-RAM Memory) and then later uses FM_1808(F-RAM Memory) to plot the signals. I'm using structure to keep all data in one function with the pointer, pointing to that function. unfortunetly i can't utilized the FRAM quite well and unable to extract the data. i need help to find where i'm doing wrong that make problem in extracting the data. thanks your help will be highly appreciated. I have attached some lines of code for where i define structure, starting address and function to extract data.

```
define.c
 #pragma DATA_SECTION(FRAMAdr,"FRAMData");
 volatile struct FRAMAddress FRAMAdr;
```

linker cmd

```
page1 
{
EXTFRAM : origin = 0x200000, length = 0x008000 
} 

Sections
{
FRAMData: > EXTFRAM    PAGE = 1
}

define.h

struct FRAMAddress {
    int16 Dat[32768];    // FRAM 16bit data & 16bit memory
};
extern volatile struct FRAMAddress FRAMAdr;

Uint16  *FRAMStartAdr = (Uint16 *)0x200000;
```

pheripheral.c

```
void FSave(Uint16 FAdr, int16 FD1, int16 FD2)
 {
FRamAdr.Dat[FAdr] = FD1;            
DELAY_US(0.2L);
FRamAdr.Dat[FAdr+5000] = FD2;

}
```

main.c

```
extern void FSave(Uint16 FAdr1, int16 FD1, int16 FD2);
{
if(FIndex<=5000)
 {
FSave(FIndex, (int16)spd, (int16)(id));
FIndex++;
 }
 else
 {
FSaveflag=0;
 }
 }
```

i would like to seek help regarding data value at memory addresses using FM_1808(F-RAM Memory).

Comment: You did not show true code; the function `FSave` is not compilable since the parameter `FAdr` hides the `struct` variable with the same name.

Comment: there was error with name so i change it. please check and if you can comment any?

Comment: How many FM1808 are there? How does it show that you're _unable to extract the data_? It might be helpful to write some fixed pattern and look at what's read back then.

Comment: There are two FM1808 on the board.  By using the above mentioned code when i checked the FD1 FD2 values there nothing in it. During debugging it doesn't show any error but at same time i can't get values.

Comment: Maybe you should also more describe, a) how many of such chips are there, and b) how are they actually connected. c) if these are parallel I/F, is your HW also driving /WE, /CE, /OE too? .. Most likely ,you would need a small driver?

Comment: yea /WE,/CE/OE are driven by the hardware. actually, all required hardware is already there especially for voltage regulations and logic circuits and peripherals select.

Comment: What do you mean by _when i checked the FD1 FD2 values there nothing in it_? I'd check with a monitor program or the attached debugger whether values can be written to the FRAM and read back.

Comment: I just checked on the ccs expression windows but didn’t got anything. Unfortunately I can’t check them on monitor. I just want to take the data value and then plot on my pc using origin or matlb.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you probably want something like this, assuming your FRAM is mapped at address 0x200000.

```
struct FRAM {
    uint16_t Dat[32768];
};

struct FRAM * FRAMData = (struct FRAM *)0x200000;

void FSave(Uint16 FAdr, int16 FD1, int16 FD2)
{
    FRAMData->Dat[FAdr] = FD1;            
    DELAY_US(0.2L);
    FRAMData->Dat[FAdr+5000] = FD2;
}
```

Note that the [datasheet](https://www.datasheets360.com/pdf/2332045279706022330) I found online suggests the FM1808 has 32K 8-bit values, not 16-bit values, so you should look into that.

Edit: Also not sure your delay is needed or makes sense. What is the type of 0.2L? What parameter type does DELAY_US() take?

Comment: Thanks for the code suggestion. I just check the code on the board but there are some address and memory problems. i have edited the above code for better understanding.

Comment: Delay is predefined function from DSP28x example header file that is #define DELAY_US(A)  DSP28x_usDelay(((((long double) A * 1000.0L) / (long double)CPU_RATE) - 9.0L) / 5.0L). yea FM1808 is 32k-8 bit and here we used FRAM 16bit data & 16bit memory